# Objets inanimés — « ça » vs. le pronom objet indirect

Tags: pronoms

La page 146 de *Advanced French Grammar* de Véronique Mazet déclare ceci :

> We established that the indirect object pronouns lui/leur could only replace human objects. However, (some of those verbs) + à + (human object) can have a non-human object. Can you still use the indirect object pronouns ? Yes, because you don't have an alternative. Note that **ça**, which can be an alternative in some cases, can't be used after a verb of communication.
>
> Exemple : I. L'économie est stagnante, il faut **lui** donner un coup de fouet.

**Question 1.** Puisque l'économie est un objet inanimé, est-il possible d'écrire ceci qui m'apparaît faux ?

> II. L'économie est stagnante, il faut donner un coup de fouet à **ça** ?

**Question 2.** Quand peut-on employer **ça** dans ce contexte ?

---

**Un supplément suite à la réponse de cl-r :**

Je vous remercie de votre réponse détaillée que je voudrais éclaircir. En d’autres termes, les deux phrases suivantes sont toutes les deux justes, la seule différence est le sens de *l’économie*, antécédent des pronoms :

> I. L’économie est malade, il faut lui donner un coup de fouet.
>
> II. L’économie est malade, il faut donner un coup de fouet à ça/cela.

Dans la phrase 1, *l’économie* désigne un système ou « une activité humaine », comme vous l’avez exprimé. Dans la phrase 2, *l’économie*  traite de « la situation dans laquelle elle se trouve », comme vous l’avez exprimé.

Si tout ce qui précède est correct, pourquoi Alexis soutient-il ci-dessous : « Question #1 : Non, cette forme n'est pas correcte » ?

---

**Un supplément suite à la réponse de Stéphane Gimenez :**

Merci beaucoup de votre réponse. Je reste perdu. D'après vous, la phrase II est possible mais n'est pas naturelle. Néanmoins, pourquoi sera-t-il plus naturel de dire la suite, ce que j'intitule III:

> III. L'économie est stagnante. Il faut remédier **à ça**.

Puisque les deux phrases font allusion au fait que « l'économie est stagnante » et comprennent la structure « à cela/ça » également, une m'apparaît aussi naturelle que l'autre.

Answer (score 1):

L'économie n'est pas un objet en soi¹, mais une activité humaine.

Le *ça* renvoie à un objet physique ou à une entité précise. *Plus jamais ça !* est une revendication que l'on entend à la suite de faits sociaux particulièrement horribles par exemple.
On ne pourrait pas dire *plus jamais elle* (pour dénoncer la corruption qui n'est pas une activité, mais un comportement, un choix de faire).

L'économie en tant qu'entité est sans cesse en évolution. Elle peut être considérée comme vivante, on lui attribue alors le *lui* de personnification.
On peut surajouter un *ça*, ou *cela* mais dans un autre contexte :

> L'économie est malade, *ça/cela lui* apprendra à ne pas savoir prévenir les crises !

En remplaçant *ça*, par *cela* :

> L'économie est stagnante, il faut donner un coup de fouet à *cela*.

est tout à fait possible ; on ne cherche pas à corriger l'économie elle-même, mais la situation dans laquelle elle se trouve (même s'il faut pour cela modifier ses modes de fonctionnement).
<sup>1.  *Précision suite aux remarques :*
Le petit Robert :**SOI** II.2 : EN SOI : de par sa nature, abstraction faite de toute autre chose.</sup>

Comment: Je vous remercie de votre réponse ! Puis-je retenir votre attention à un supplément avec lequel j'ai mis à jour mon message original ? De plus, je pense que vous vouliez dire « L'économie ... en **soi**, mais une activité humaine » dans votre première phrase. J'ai demandé de la faire corrigé.

Comment: @LaPrevoyance, j'ai ajouté une annotation pour préciser le sens que je donne à *soi* - N.B. : **Le petit Robert** est le dictionnaire que j'utilise en permanence, les autres (papier ou en ligne) ne sont ouverts que pour des recherches très particulières. Si je n'en avais qu'un à acheter ce serait celui-la car il répond à pratiquement tous les problèmes que pose la pratique du français, et ceci de façon condensée, judicieuse et limpide. - P.S. Je n'ai aucun intérêt financier ou autre avec l'éditeur.

Comment: Merci de votre second commentaire. Puis-je vous attirer votre attention sur mon supplément dans mon post original ?

Answer (score 1):

*Ça* is a demonstrative pronoun (it replaces *cela*) and applies to a non-human object (unless you want to be sarcastic).

*Lui* is a personal pronoun for the third person singular of indirect object complement. *Leur* is the same for plural.

So I dont know exactly what you mean by “replacing *lui* by *ça*”. It depends on what you mean:

> L'économie est malade, il faut lui donner un coup de fouet. (lui = l'économie, COI)
>
> Je sais ça ne se passe pas comme prévu, c'est lent, inactif mais croyez-moi, je vais donner un bon coup de fouet à tout ça.

Answer (score 1):

La réponse à la première question est non : « à ça » n'est pas possible dans la phrase II. Utiliser « à celle-ci » serait possible mais pas vraiment naturel. Le pronom personnel « lui » est vraiment la meilleure solution.

Néanmoins ceci est possible :

> L'économie est stagnante, il faut donner un coup de fouet à tout ça.

Mais il faut bien se rendre compte que *tout ça* et un pronom qui englobe une situation générale, ce n'est pas un pronom qui référence directement « l'économie ». Enlever l'adverbe *tout* sonne faux parce que *ça* seul est utilisé pour référencer une proposition entière. On ne donne pas un coup de fouet à « l'économie est stagnante », seulement à « l'économie ». Voici un exemple correct dans lequel *ça* référence une proposition entière :

> L'économie est stagnante. Il faut remédier à ça.

Cela signifie qu'il faut remédier au fait que « l'économie est stagnante ». Petite remarque au passage : employer le pronom *y* est aussi possible.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Puis-je diriger votre attention vers un supplément que je viens de présenter dans mon poste original ?

Answer (score 0):

Question #1 : Non, cette forme, même si elle est grammaticalement correcte, sonne vraiment faux.

Question #2 : Je ne vois pas d'exemples qui permettraient l'utilisation de *ça* dans ce contexte.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Trouvé le titre d'un livre http://www.decitre.fr/livres/sur-la-definition-de-l-economie-politique-et-sur-la-methode-d-investigation-qui-lui-est-propre-9782912673268.html : `Sur la définition de l'économie politique ; et sur la méthode d'investigation qui lui est propre `. Il semble donc que votre première réponse peut être contre-dite - Pour LaPrevoyance (on a droit à une seul arobase par commentaire) : j'ai oublié d'adresser à Alexis mon premier commentaire négatif.